# Save the Infopath 2010 Form to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: infopath, form

I have designed an Infopath 2010 Form and published as Document Template of the library. Now, Whenever I try to add a new Document on the Library, it loads the Infopath however if I click on Save, it is throwing a popup window as asking for the name to save

[image]

Also it is not getting closed and redirected to the All documents page of the library.

I dont want to have the pop asking for the Filename and when I click on Save button it should save automatically with the name mentioned on the field of the Infopath form and should redirect to the All documents page of the library.

Comment: You have configured the submit options and its not working as configured or you want to know how to configure the submit options to have the desired behavior?

Comment: I want to know how to configure the submit options to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: My expectation is that Infopath form should load on the "Add documet" click, and user should be able to fill. Once the form is filled and clicked on save button, it should save as a document into the document library. Note, the form also has property promotion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the form in desighn mode
2. Go to submit options
3. Add new connection
4. Follow the wizard and specify the formula for the file name
5. Choose to close the form after submitting
6. Republish the form

Here is one article with more details
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1670194&seqNum=5